# Where should I .lock() when one thread is going through an ArrayList and another one is adding elements into the ArrayList

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I have two Threads. One is iterating through an ArrayList and one is adding elements into it.

```
private static final List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
```

On the main Thread:

```
public void onStop()
{
... //createFile
fileNames.add(fileName);
}
```

On a background Thread:

```
public void analyze()
{
Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int i=0;i<fileNames.size();i++) {
                  //do stuff
            }
        };
        thread.start();
}
```

Should I just .lock() only when adding elements?